# Different Q. about displaying images using XSLT & XHTML

Tags: xml, image, xslt, xhtml

Okay, I have 2 XML (one for Anime & Movies) files (with the same tags & DTD, so you only need to see the format for 1 of the XML files). 1 XML (the Movie XML file) file has the following format...

```
<Stories>
<Fan_Fiction>
    <Genre> Movie </Genre>
    <World> The Matrix </World>
    <Story>
        <Title Alternative_Title="The Matrix Sensolutions"> The Matrix Revolverlutions </Title>
        <Year_Made> 2003 </Year_Made>
        <Author Gender="Male">
            <First_Name> James </First_Name>
            <Last_Name> Blake </Last_Name>
        </Author>
        <Author_Country> Unknown </Author_Country>
        <Language> English </Language>
        <Theme> Reality </Theme>
        <Theme> Artificial Intelligence </Theme>
        <Theme> Freedom </Theme>
        <Content_Warning> Intense violence. Nudity. Strong language. Drug use. </Content_Warning>
        <Description> In this alternative ending to the Matrix trilogy; we find Neo has survived his epic battle with Smith.
        However, freeing humanity from the Matrix is proving more difficult than expected </Description>
        <Link> http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Neo </Link>
        <Image> Neo.jpg </Image>
    </Story>
</Fan_Fiction>
```

Yes, I have a “Fan_Fiction” tag (with all the child tags) for each movie in the XML file.

Basically, the 2nd XML (an Anime themed XML file) file has the exact same format, except it has "Anime" inside every “Genre” tag.

Okay, now I have an XSLT file that will output both of these XML files into HTML (I can link both XML files to the one XSL file because they share the same tags & DTD). My Q. is how can I use a HTML command (the `"<img src=" " />"` command in my XSLT file) to display the images (the "Neo.jpg" part of the XML file) that are NAMED in the 2 XML files.

Okay, so it seems like a lot, but basically I was told that it was possible to use the `"<img src=" " />"` command in my XSL document so that when I "run" the 2 XML files, they will reference my XSLT file & display their images respectively. How do you do this using a HTML command within XSLT so that it will work for both documents?

Comment: Would it be possible to show the XSLT you are currently using? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I put the full code above. I'll try & see if your way works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had to do that, I came up with

```xsl
<img alt="">
 <xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:value-of select="Stories/Fan_Fiction/Story/Image"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

in the XSLT file. It looks a bit silly with the `</img>` and all, but it works fine! In Firefox and Opera, that is. Chrome doesn't seem to want to cooperate, so you may have to experiment a bit. Anyway, I hope this helps.

Edit: Here is a more complete xsl file, that works with the file in your question and loops over all the Fan_Fiction elements.

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <title>Fanfix</title>
   <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Stories/Fan_Fiction">
     <h1><xsl:value-of select="World"/></h1>
     <h2><xsl:value-of select="Story/Title"/></h2>
     <img alt="">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="Story/Image"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
     </img>
     <p>Author: <xsl:value-of select="Story/Author/First_Name"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="Story/Author/Last_Name"/></p>
     <p>etc</p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've put a demo on http://strictquirks.nl/temp/neo/stories.xml so that you can see it in action.

By the way, I had to remove the spaces around the img name in the XML, because that was the reason it didn't work in Chrome: Chrome thought the filename contained spaces.

Comment: No, since you changed the structure of the XML file. With your updated question, the path becomes `Stories/Fan_Fiction/Story/Image`. See edited answer.

Comment: That isn't working... I put that code within a for-each "Fan_Fiction" XSLT statement?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer with a more complete xsl file. Hope this helps! Demo [here](http://strictquirks.nl/temp/neo/stories.xml).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much! +1. I'm new to this... and my teacher can't even do this... but expects us to!

Comment: Thank you for trying to understand this (shown by your amendments & so on).

Comment: You're welcome. Can you accept this answer by clicking on the check mark? That way, future visitors can see that the issue is solved.